# How to get replication table in accumulo

Tags: accumulo, geomesa

While ingesting data into Accumulo it freezes. Below are the logs from master server.

> [tableOps.Utils] INFO : table !0 (60b7e8cebdb385a4) locked for read operation: COMPACT
>   [tableOps.CompactRange] INFO : No iterators or compaction strategy
>
> [zookeeper.DistributedReadWriteLock] INFO : Added lock entry 0 userData 67ad2c7dd8f6e38f lockType
>
> READ
>   [tableOps.Utils] INFO : namespace +accumulo (67ad2c7dd8f6e38f) locked for read operation:
>
> COMPACT
>   [zookeeper.DistributedReadWriteLock] INFO : Added lock entry 0 userData 67ad2c7dd8f6e38f lockType
>
> READ
>   [tableOps.Utils] INFO : table +r (67ad2c7dd8f6e38f) locked for read operation: COMPACT
>
> [replication.WorkMaker] INFO : Replication table is not yet online
>
> [replication.WorkMaker] INFO : Replication table is not yet online
>
> [replication.WorkMaker] INFO : Replication table is not yet online
>
> [replication.WorkMaker] INFO : Replication table is not yet online

is there any way to get the replication table online.

(I am very new to Accumulo and still reading it's internals).

Comment: How much RAM have you given the various Accumulo processes?  I'm wondering if some of those are constrained and having trouble starting up?

Comment: for sample ingestion into the cluster I am assigning 3.75 GB of ram to each of the node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question. The replication table is for the data-center replication feature and has nothing to do with you ingesting data.

Look at the TabletServer logs as the Master is not involved in the ingesting of data to your system.